# WPF ListViewItem Colors Incorrect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've setup a very basic test to troubleshoot a color issue I have in WPF targeting .NET Framework 4 using Visual Studio 2012 and running on Windows 8.1.

The problem is that the IsSelected and IsMouseOver trigger properties produce incorrect colors to the screen, while Snoop shows correct values. The actual colors displayed on the screen are more "washed out". That is, they appear lighter than they should. One appears as #E5F3FB and the other appears as #CBE8F6, but I haven't used either color in my XAML.

Screenshot: I had to do some monkey business here because Snoop changes background colors on selected items. What you see here is what the user would see without snoop running. You can see that Snoop indicates a darker blue, which is the way it should be.

[image: WPF Color Issue]

And now here's my code (withholding only the little bit of code behind needed to produce the four items on the screen, which I'll be happy to post if it would be helpful).

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColorTest"
    x:Class="MainWindow" Name="MainWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="GroupsListView"  
                          BorderThickness="0" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#777777" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0072C6" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2A8DD4" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                               ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                               MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                               ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="140" Height="25">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why ListView? I would take ListBox here.

Comment: Try checking your Windows Color Manager settings, sometimes the settings there produce the wrong shades of colors.

Comment: Is it still experienced if you include the Alpha in your RGB? Like #FF0072C6 instead of #0072C6?

Comment: @hedgehog, what's your point? I want to use a ListView. Using a listbox is not an option.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, same problem with full hex.

Comment: @BenVlodgi Color Management > Advanced > everything set to system default. Have never been in that screen before so I haven't changed anything. Computer is an almost new Dell 6430U Ultrabook. I don't have another Win8 machine handy to test it on right now but could day that in a day or two.

Comment: I seem to recall a Setter in the base template that will set its Opacity to 0.7 which looks about like the difference in your example. Worth investigating, I can look more when free time comes up.

Comment: OK, I've tried setting opacity in my above style to 1 and to 0 and neither of them show the correct color.

Comment: Why is ListView not an option?  ListView has some very advanced templates.  If you want direct control then I go ListBox every time.

Comment: @Blam Moving to a listbox is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: ListView is overwhelming this. Actually ListBox might be the answer to this question. Might... We do not have your code to try it out but ListBox uses ListBoxItem and that has a completely different Style ControlTemplate and Triggers than ListViewItem does.

Comment: @devhedgehog But that would just be a work around. It doesn't tell us why the ListView produces the wrong colors. The code I've posted is an example only. The actual application is different than this, but has the same problem.

Comment: @HK1 It wouldn't be a workaround. It would be the solution. The reason why your style trigger doesn't fire is because of the definition of ListViewItem's ControlTemplate's Trigger. The Trigger is not working with parent template's background color. To sum up solution is another custom ControlTemplate definition.

Comment: I've changed my ListView to a Listbox and still have the same issue, both in my test application and in my real application.

Comment: Just adding to this that the problem doesn't exist on Windows 7.

Comment: You're not the only one who has this issue, @HK1. If you managed to resolve it, please let me know.