# WPF custom templated ListBox shows incorrect color on IsSelected

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, listbox

**TLDR version**

In a WPF app, running on Windows 10, I have a ListBox with a custom template, including a specification for the text Foreground color when an item IsSelected becomes true. The color should be #FFBF00, but shows up much lighter or "washed out". If I change the color to something else, I get the same effect (similar color, but lighter). The other colors in the app are showing up correctly (so it's not a display issue).

From what I've found (see Related Issues), this appears to have to do with changes that came in Windows 8 (or the associated .NET framework version) and I have yet to find a solution or workaround.

**Details**

Here is the custom style/template for the ListBox:

```
<Style x:Key="WorkflowRibbon" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Border ClipToBounds="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <AlternationConverter x:Key="BackgroundBrushes">
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.65"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.45"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.31"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.20"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.10"/>
                        </AlternationConverter>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="PhaseSelectedAnimation" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ForegroundBrush"
                                            To="#ffbf00">
                                <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase Power="2"/>
                                </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </ColorAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Scale"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="RibbonLabel"
                                             To="1.1">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase Power="2"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="PhaseDeselectedAnimation" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ForegroundBrush">
                                <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase Power="2"/>
                                </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </ColorAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Scale"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="RibbonLabel">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase Power="2"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="PhaseSelectedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource PhaseSelectedAnimation}"/>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard  x:Name="PhaseDeselectedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource PhaseDeselectedAnimation}"/>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <local:WorkflowRibbonLabel WorkflowPhase="{Binding}" 
                                               x:Name="RibbonLabel"
                                               BorderThickness="0"
                                               Scale="1.0"
                                               Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Converter={StaticResource BackgroundBrushes}}">
                        <local:WorkflowRibbonLabel.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ForegroundBrush" Color="#ffffff" Opacity="1"/>
                        </local:WorkflowRibbonLabel.Foreground>
                    </local:WorkflowRibbonLabel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-1"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

This style is working perfectly in every respect, other than the color issue. Note that this animation:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                Storyboard.TargetName="ForegroundBrush"
                To="#ffbf00">
    <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
        <PowerEase Power="2"/>
    </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
</ColorAnimation>
```

Gets called via the IsSelected trigger and does result in a color change (just to the wrong color):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
             Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="PhaseSelectedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource PhaseSelectedAnimation}"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Washed out color, as displayed]

Here is what it *should* look like (just a sketch, only the yellow font color is important here, ignore the other differences):

[image: The correct color]

**Related issues**

- [This issue appears to be very similar, if not the same, and
  indicates that this may only happen on Windows 8+ and not on Windows
  7 and earlier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181199/wpf-listviewitem-colors-incorrect) Unfortunately I do not have a Windows 7 system to test this on.
- [This appears to be the same issue (possibly by the same person)
  described on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/feed0f3c-7747-4d2d-ad2c-5bfcadb2c7bc/wpf-listviewitem-style-trigger-colors-are-incorrect-on-windows-81?forum=wpf)
- [This is a bug file with MS for the issue where it appears to be
  acknowledged, but with no fix or workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/846189/wpf-listviewitem-background-color-incorrect-on-windows-8-x)

So any ideas for solutions or workarounds? I'm hoping to avoid having to write an entirely custom control (but that may be what it comes down to).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Windows 8 stuff was a red herring. The key snippet is here:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="PhaseDeselectedAnimation" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ForegroundBrush">
                                <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase Power="2"/>
                                </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </ColorAnimation>
```

I assumed that the `ColorAnimation` would inherit its `Duration` from the parent `Storyboard`. That assumption is incorrect. Apparently the `ColorAnimation` will revert to its default `Duration` (1s, I believe). So when the overall animation finishes and implements `HoldEnd`, the `ColorAnimation` has only completed part of its transition to the final color, which is why it displays another color that is "just off" the desired color.

Solving this problem amounted to simply explicitly setting the `Duration` property on the `ColorAnimation`, like so:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="PhaseDeselectedAnimation" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="ForegroundBrush">
                                <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase Power="2"/>
                                </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </ColorAnimation>
```